# Permission issue with Android 13 / SDK 33 accessing gallery?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the device photo gallery, I can successfully access the camera and take a photo, however the access to gallery appears to be denied, even though Camera, Photos And Videos permission have been granted.

Here is the method used for the click on accessing gallery;

I am testing using Android 13 device (Oppo X3)

Targeting SDK 32 = Works fine

Targeting SDK 33 = Error

```
case R.id.relativeLayoutEditor:
  String[] arrPermissionsEdit = {
    "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.CAMERA",
    "android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
  };
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) arrPermissionsEdit = new String[] {
  "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
  "android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
};
Dexter.withContext(HomeActivity.this).withPermissions(arrPermissionsEdit).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
  public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
    if (multiplePermissionsReport.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      intent.setType("image/*");
      String[] mimetypes = {
        "image/*"
      };
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
      startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

    if (multiplePermissionsReport.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
      DetailsDialog.showDetailsDialog(HomeActivity.this);
    }
  }

  public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List < PermissionRequest > list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
  }

}).withErrorListener(dexterError -> Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error occurred! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()).onSameThread().check();

return;
```

Comment: "the access to gallery appears to be denied" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: I still receive the prompt that the app requires additional permissions, it does not go any further. It seems to think this line is active, when it isn't   `if (multiplePermissionsReport.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            DetailsDialog.showDetailsDialog(HomeActivity.this);
                        }`

Comment: You do not need any permission to use ACTION_PICK. So just start the beast.

Comment: @DannyRoy - Were you able to make this work for android 13? If yes, can you post here please?

Comment: No, when I set the target to API level 32 it works, so I just left it at that for now.

Comment: Any solutions for this issue